# Java - Load Raw Gray Pixel Data into BufferedImage

Tags: java, performance, arrays, bufferedimage

I need to load raw pixel data from file to a BufferedImage. The image is gray with 8-bit pixel format. So I would start like that:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[640 * 480];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/test.dat");
fis.read(bytes);
fis.close();
```

But with this I'm creating a buffer in between. Can I load bytes directly into the image ? Or if not can I like *memcpy* the bytes into the image ? Speed is very important for this. All in Java of course.

Comment: Be sure *file-I/O* will be the bottleneck. But still a good question related to the memory usage for the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this seems to be: impossible without an extra buffer in-between.